# regex get rid of capturing groups

Tags: python, regex, capturing-group

I have the following regex:
`(?i)p\w+@t(-)?\w+(-\w+)?(\.\w+)?\.at` which is matching data like

```
papFoo@t-bar.at
PapBar@tfoo.ring.at
```

How can I rewrite this regex to use **non-captchuring** groups?

- `[?i]p\w+@t[-]?\w+[-\w+]?[\.\w+]?\.at` will no longer match any results
- `(?:?i)p\w+@t(?:-)?\w+(?:-\w+)?(?:\.\w+)?\.at` same here

I.e. `(?i)p` should be writable as `?ip` I think but on https://regex101.com I only get errors when trying to use `(?:?i)p\w+@t(?:-)?\w+(?:-\w+)?(?:\.\w+)?\.at` with non-captchuring groups.

In the end python3 should evaluate the regex.

Comment: Your [**expression works**](https://regex101.com/r/wHgZNz/1) - just put the modifier outside of the expression or use [**`(?i)p\w+@t(?:-)?\w+(?:-\w+)?(?:\.\w+)?\.at`**](https://regex101.com/r/wHgZNz/2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first "group", `(?i)`, is not a capturing group, it's a flag set, turning on case-insensitivity for the expression. The non-capturing version should be:

```
(?i)p\w+@t-?\w+(?:-\w+)?(?:\.\w+)?\.at
```

Which matches correctly.

Comment: This is included in the very first section of the "EXPLANATION" pane when you paste your original expression into regex101, the site you mentioned: "(?i) match the remainder of the pattern with the following effective flags: gi
i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])"

Comment: For the fish +1 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
(?i)p\w+@t(?:-)?\w+(?:-\w+)?(?:\.\w+)?\.at
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/wHgZNz/2/).
As pointed out by others, the `(?i)` is an inline modifier as is `(?s)` (singleline) or `(?m)` (multiline).

Comment: No explanation of why this works and the original does not?